# Laravel email configuration: what am I missing?

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I can send emails via [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but not via Laravel. I assume my Laravel configuration to be wrong.

I'm sending from my local development environment.

**Laravel error**

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "name@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators
```

**Laravel controller**

```
// ...
Mail::to('anyone@whatever.com')->send(new AnyEmailTemplate());
// ...
```

**Laravel config/mail.php**

```
return [
  'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
  'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.anyprovider.com'),
  'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
  'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'name@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'example.com'),
  ],
  'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
  'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'name@example.com'),
  'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'supersecretpassword'),
  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
  'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',
    'paths' => [
      resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
  ],
]
```

**Laravel .env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.anyprovider.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=name@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**PHPMailer script** (works)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.anyprovider.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'name@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'supersecretpassword';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('name@example.com', 'example.com');
$mail->addAddress('anyone@whatever.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Any subject';
$body = "Any content";
$altBody = "Any alternative content";
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $altBody;
$mail->send();
```

Any idea how to configure Laravel, based on the settings used with `PHPMailer`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to change info about encryption

Comment: @GiacomoM I tried `starttls` and `SSL`. Both didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: did you try nulling it?

Comment: Can you post your `.env` settings?

Comment: @GiacomoM Just tried `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', null)`. Same error.

Comment: Check `.env` settings (the .env file overwrites your config file) and do not use "null" but just an empty string. After that clean the cache and try this command `php composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I just added the relevant part of my `.env`

Comment: @Mr.B. Can you try `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=FALSE` once ?

Comment: If you just added the configuration into .evn, try to clear your cache and try again.

Comment: Can you name specific provider of the relay host? e.g. Gmail may require turning on "less secure apps" or fail into "login via web because we say w have some suspicions".

Comment: Have you cached your configuration by any chance? Clear it with `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: @GiacomoM the solution was setting the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to empty string in the `.env` and `config/mail.php`. Afterwards cache clearing and `php composer dump-autoload`. Please post it as an answer an I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your PHPMailer script you should empty the value of MAIL_ENCRYPTION.

Remember that if you have an .env file, this overrides your config/mail.php file.

In your case your .env file becomes:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=mail.anyprovider.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=name@example.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

While your config/mail.php becomes:

```
...
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''), 
...
```

**NOTE**
After edit the files you have to tell to laravel about these changes with:

- Cleaning the cache
- Executing the command `php artisan dump-autoload`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The problem is we use mixed characters for `MAIL_PASSWORD` like `#` that use for comment in `.env` file.

My problem solved after change password to some simple password without any symbols

Comment: Or simply put quotes around it: `MAIL_PASSWORD="supersecret#password"`

Comment: @Saman thank you. It didn't solve my problem, but is useful to know. +1

Comment: this solved my problems after 3 days of swearing :)